# Selecting top result from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is i think a simple problem but i can't seem to solve it.

I want to select the newest result from a table and join it with a single element in another table.

To put it better, here's a simple schema:

```
Table 1 - Person
personId -PK - INT - AUTO ID
name - VARCHAR

Table 2 - Event
eventId - PK - INT - AUTO ID
personId - FK
timestamp  - DATETIME
event - ENUM ('Went Out', 'Came back')
```

What I'd like to do is return a list of all people and the latest action each person performed

Example Result:

> name| personId | timestamp | eventId | event
>
> bob   |  1 |    2011-08-7   3    |   'went out'

I did a simple query joining the two tables and then did a group by personId and order by timestamp but the result that was returned was always the first action for the person, not their latest.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This may be a rather obvious question, but: You were ordering the timestamp in DESCENDING order, right?

Comment: Added the `[greatest-n-per-group-tag]`. Follow the links on the right, under the **Related** header. Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

Comment: And an excellent explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/7745635#7745635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t1.Name,
  t1.PersonId,
  t2.TimeStamp,
  t2.EventId,
  t2.Event
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.PersonId = t1.PersonID
INNER JOIN (SELECT
              PersonId,
              MAX(TimeStamp) as LastEventDateTime
            FROM Table2 
            GROUP BY PersonID) LE 
  ON LE.PersonID = t2.PersonID 
    AND LE.LastEventDateTime = t2.TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.name, p.personId, e.timestamp, e.eventId, e.event
FROM person p
  INNER JOIN Event e 
    ON e.eventId = 
      ( SELECT MAX(eventId)
        FROM Event 
        WHERE personId = p.personId 
        GROUP BY personId 
        LIMIT 1 )
```

OR

```
SELECT p.Name, p.ID, me.timestamp, me.ID, me.event
FROM person p
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id, timestamp, event
            FROM Event 
            WHERE personId = p.ID               
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
           ) me
ON p.ID = me.id
```

PS: sorry but can't test both queries right now

Comment: No need for `MAX(ID)`. You can have `ORDER BY whatever LIMIT 1`

Comment: If 'Id' is a (guaranteed) incrementing number and it's indexed then the most efficient way to query the database would be Max(Id).  This is called a 'Covered Key', I think.  I don't wish to argue with the logic of this answer but there is a little trick here you might want to consider.

Comment: @Hugh Jones : initially I've used MAX(ID) but then changed. Interesting to ask `ypercube` why he suggested this, really I did not paid much attention to this, my bad anyway

Comment: tried both queries, the first query went mad and returned every person linked to every event, which makes no sense as the WHERE wouldn't have been true... the second i couldn't get to work as it couldn't find p.ID

Comment: @Ciaran Fisher : I believe you got the idea so please tweak it slightly if required or provide more infor regarding what is not working, anyway I have not DB in hand to check queries right now

Comment: @Hugh: If `id` and `timestamp` define the same order, yes, `ORDER BY id` or `MAX(id)` would be faster then `ORDER BY timestamp`. The `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` has an advantage over `MAX(ID)` as you can show the whole row, as in the first query, without need for a subquery.

Comment: @ypercube : agreed.  I reckon 'slightly faster' will turn out to be an understatement, though.

Comment: @Ciaran: Try again the first query. It should work correctly now. There was probably a mixup of the 2 ids.

Comment: @Hugh: I already corrected that to just 'faster'. But it won't be much of a difference as only 1 result is needed to be read from the index. The differnce comes when you want to do `LIMIT x` and the clustered index (which is usually the id) results in sequential readings from the disk.

Comment: Thats for your help man, the first query works now but it's a lot slower than the answer i accepted. The query is working on a dataset of 85,000 events and around 500 people.

Comment: @Ciaran Fisher : I believe this is because ORDER BY, I'll change to MAX(ID) as in initial my answer, it should be faster

Comment: @Ciaran Fisher : Do please tell us if/how much faster the Max(Id) technique is :)

Comment: @HughJones - Results are very interesting! With Max(id) the results are pretty much identical between both queries over 10 runs

Comment: @Ciaran : ok - then go with the safer option (but dont tell ypercube he was right ;P)

Answer (score 0):

you'd want to do an

```
ORDER by `timestamp` DESC
```

(desc from descending) to get the highest timestamp value instead of the lowest

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI standard way would be:

```
select name, personid, timestamp, eventid, event
from person
join event on event.personid=person.personid
  and event.timestamp=(select max(timestamp) from event e2
                       where e2.personid=person.personid)
```

I haven't used MySQL in a while and I don't have an installation handy, but you might get what you want with:

```
select name, personid, timestamp, eventid, event
from person
join event on event.personid=person.personid
group by personid
order by personid, timestamp desc
```

It's non-standard because by the standard, anything in the select must be in the group-by or be an aggregate, and here we don't want to do either. But as I recall MySQL doesn't require that, so I'd give this a whirl and see what happens.

Comment: the bottom query is what i actually tried first but for some reason it always results in the first event the person performed instead of the latest

Comment: @Jay: your second query will not work as expected, not even in MySQL.

Comment: As for standards, you can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards/7596265#7596265

Comment: Okay, disregard the second query. As I said, I don't have a MySQL install handy so I couldn't test it, and it would bounce with a syntax error in standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, making use of a covered key, assumes that `order by Id` would yield the same results as `order by timestamp`

```
SELECT p.Name, p.ID, me.timestamp, me.ID, me.event
FROM person p
JOIN (
      SELECT personId, MAX(ID) id 
      FROM Event 
      WHERE personId = p.ID               
      GROUP BY personId
     ) me
ON p.ID = me.id
```

`Order by timestamp` is more natural and probably safer, but this is quicker.