# min(column) is not returning me correct data of other columns

Tags: mysql, min

Below is what I have

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id + myDate       + name
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
'A'+ '2012-06-05' + 'baz'
'A'+ '2012-06-04' + 'bar'
'B'+ '2012-06-05' + 'foo'
'C'+ '2012-06-05' + 'bla'
'C'+ '2012-06-04' + 'blah'
'C'+ '2012-06-06' + 'bleh'
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Query I am using is

```
SELECT id, min(myDate) as Date, name 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

I am getting output as below

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id + myDate       + name
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
'A'+ '2012-06-04' + 'baz'
'B'+ '2012-06-05' + 'foo'
'C'+ '2012-06-04' + 'bla'
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

---

My question is when query is giving me correct date, why data of column `name` is coming as *baz* instead of *bar* as `name` for date `2012-06-04` is *bar*.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e98/1) to test data.

Comment: If you want to select additional fields (which are not used in grouping) then you should use another query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by/10999689#10999689

Comment: @dystroy Of course you can answer;-) I just gave a link to example.

Comment: @Devart : I know the solution, however my question is WHY min() is not giving me desired result?? Why I have to use another query??

Comment: @dystroy : Stop doing edit in my question.

Comment: @FahimParkar See my answer for an explanation why this happens. In short, `min` only gives you the minimum date. You can use `min` for name too, but that would give you the first (alphabetically) name, and not the name that goes with the lowest date.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar - Itay Moav and GolezTrol answered on this question. That is why Sql Server, Oracle and other databases do not allow non-aggregated columns in FROM clause; you would get an error with such query.

Comment: Why the downvotes, This sounds like a good question, on the behaviour of GROUP BY. Atleast give feedback so OP can improve quality!

Comment: @dystroy : Nothing personal. Frankly after reading Golez answer, I got point. You answer was not giving me idea where I was getting wrong. AND STOP BEING RUDE. I know you are the one who downvote me...

Comment: 2 downvotes and 1 vote for Close?? What was problem in question??

Comment: It is a good question. Do not understand why -1. There are many similar questions in SO, but almost nobody asks about the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You grab

1. the id,
2. the lowest date for that id, and
3. *any* of the names that go with it.

Other (normal) databases won't even allow this query. They would force you to either use an aggregate function for **name**, or add **name** to the `group by` as well. MySQL instead picks a random value, and there's your problem.

To solve this, your query will become slighly more complex:

```
select
  t.id, 
  t.mydate,
  t.name
from
  myTable t
where
  t.mydate = 
    (select 
      min(td.mydate) 
    from 
      myTable td 
    where 
      td.id = t.id)
```

Or:

```
select
  t.id, 
  t.mydate as date,
  t.name
from
  myTable t
  inner join 
    (select 
      td.id
      min(td.mydate) as date
    from 
      myTable td 
    group by 
      td.id) tx on tx.id = t.id and tx.date = t.mydate
```

Comment: Here is a simpler and quicker way of matching the correct id when using GROUP BY clause. The logic is very simple, group by selects the other columns from the row that comes first.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different query, as was pointed by DevArt :

```
SELECT m.* from myTable m join
(select id, min(myDate) md from myTable group by id) mm
on m.id=mm.id and m.myDate=md
```

Your existing query don't specify a constraint on the name column, that's the reason why you don't get the result you were expecting. `Group by` only makes a set from which you can take values, using functions like `min`, or randomly if you don't specify anything as you did.

Comment: I know the solution, however my question is WHY min() is not giving me desired result?? Why I have to use another query??

Comment: min **is** giving you the correct min on the specified column (myDate). You just haven't specified what you want for the name column.

Comment: What you mean by "You just haven't specified what you want for the other columns."?? What is name column in query???

Comment: There is a `name` column in your table. There is nothing in your query that says to mysql what value it should take on all the ones that are in the set produced by `group by`. That's the reason why a join is needed.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question, All u need to do is apply the MIN function to a concatenated field:

```
SELECT id, min(CONCAT(myDate,' ++ ',name)) as date_name 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

and process it in your server-side script

---

You are using a GROPU BY. Which means each row in result represents a **group** of values.
One of those values is the group name (the value of the field you grouped by). The rest are arbitrary values from within that group.
For example the following table:

```
F1   |   F2
1         aa
1         bb
1         cc
2         gg
2         hh
```

If u will group by F1: `SELECT F1,F2 from T GROUP BY F1`
You will get two rows:

```
1    and one value from (aa,bb,cc)
2    and one value from (gg,hh)
```

If u want a deterministic result set, you need to tell the software what algorithem to apply to the group. Several for example:

1. MIN
2. MAX
3. COUNT
4. SUM

etc etc

In your case, u did not apply a deterministic algorithem to the `name` field, so u get a "random" result from the set.