# mysql ORDER BY MIN() not matching up with id

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, min

I have a database that has the following columns:

```
-------------------
id|domain|hit_count
-------------------
```

And I would like to perform this query on it:

```
SELECT id,MIN(hit_count)
  FROM table WHERE domain='$domain'
 GROUP BY domain ORDER BY MIN(hit_count)
```

I would like this query to give me the id of the row that had the smallest hit_count for $domain. The only problem is that if I have two rows that have the same domain, say www.bestbuy.com, the query will just group by whichever one came first, and then although I will get the correct lowest hit_count, the id may or may not be the id of the row that has the lowest hit_count.

Does anyone know of a way for me to perform this query and to get the id that matches up with MIN(hit_count)? Thanks!

Comment: don't use `table` as table name. table is reserved keyword in MYSQL

Comment: Thanks. I was just putting that in for the example instead of my real table name. Good to know though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,MIN(hit_count),domain FROM table GROUP BY domain HAVING domain='$domain'
```

Comment: This needs an explanation. Unless I'm missing something, it also forgets the ORDER BY that the asker wanted.

Answer (score 1):

See, when you're using aggregates, either via aggregate functions (and `min()` is such a function) or via `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` operators, your data is being grouped. In your case it is grouped by domain. You have 2 fields in your select list, `id` and `min(hit_count)`.

Now, for each group database knows which `hit_count` to pick, as you've specified this explicitly via the aggregate function. But what about `id` — which one should be included?
MySQL internally wraps such fields into `max()` aggregate function, which I find an error prone approach. In all other RDBMSes you *will* get an error for such a query.

The rule is: if you use aggregates, then *all* columns should be either arguments of aggregate functions or arguments of `GROUP BY` operator.

To achieve the desired result, you need a subquery:

```sql
SELECT id, domain, hit_count
  FROM `table`
 WHERE domain = '$domain'
   AND hit_count = (SELECT min(hit_count) FROM `table` WHERE domain = '$domain');
```

I've used backticks, as `table` is a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,hit_count
  FROM table WHERE domain='$domain'
 GROUP BY domain ORDER BY hit_count ASC;
```

This should also work:

```
select id, MIN(hit_count) from table where domain="$domain";
```

Comment: you just want the row id with minimum hit-count for the particular domain.right !!

Comment: how can you use aggregate function without GROUP BY clause when selecting multiple fields?

Comment: why can't we use aggregate function without GROUP BY ?? And srchulo only wants the id of row with minimum count of particular domain.Thanks

Comment: you are not selecting id only. you are selecting id and min(hit_count)

Comment: yeah I am selecting both id and min(hit_count).That's not a problem.If I get the row ,I can select *(all) too from that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    hit_count
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    domain='$domain'
    AND hit_count = (SELECT MIN(hit_count) FROM table WHERE domain='$domain')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same question. Please see that question below.

***[min(column) is not returning me correct data of other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010599/mincolumn-is-not-returning-me-correct-data-of-other-columns)***

You are using a GROPU BY. Which means each row in result represents a **group** of values.
One of those values is the group name (the value of the field you grouped by). The rest are arbitrary values from within that group.
For example the following table:

```
F1   |   F2
1         aa
1         bb
1         cc
2         gg
2         hh
```

If u will group by F1: `SELECT F1,F2 from T GROUP BY F1`
You will get two rows:

```
1    and one value from (aa,bb,cc)
2    and one value from (gg,hh)
```

If u want a deterministic result set, you need to tell the software what algorithem to apply to the group. Several for example:

1. MIN
2. MAX
3. COUNT
4. SUM

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a most simplist way your query is OK just modify it with DESC keyword after GROUP BY domain

```
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(hit_count)
FROM table
WHERE domain = '$domain'
GROUP BY domain DESC
ORDER BY MIN(hit_count)
```

Explanation:
When you use group by with aggregate function it always selects the first record but if you restrict it with desc keyword it will select the lowest or last record of that group.
For testing puspose use this query that has only group_concat added.

```
SELECT
  group_concat(id),
  MIN(hit_count)
FROM table
WHERE domain = '$domain'
GROUP BY domain DESC
ORDER BY MIN(hit_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can have duplicated domains group by id:

```
SELECT id,MIN(hit_count)
FROM domain WHERE domain='$domain'
GROUP BY id ORDER BY MIN(hit_count)
```