# How to order grouped results using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to figure this out for some time now and just can't seem to make it work. I have a table that looks similar to this.

Table: Issues

```
id  yearly_issue    year    stock   created_at      updated_at      magazine_id 
1   10              2000    1       [timestamp]     [timestamp]     3
2   12              1994    6       [timestamp]     [timestamp]     10
3   36              2007    10      [timestamp]     [timestamp]     102
4   6               2002    7       [timestamp]     [timestamp]     7
5   6               2002    2       [timestamp]     [timestamp]     5
6   12              2003    9       [timestamp]     [timestamp]     10
7   11              2003    12      [timestamp]     [timestamp]     10
```

My problem is that I need to sort it (easy!) but, I only want to get one of each magazine (column magazine_id).

My Eloquent query as of now is:

```php
$issues = Issue::where('stock', ($all ? '>=' : '>'), 0)
  ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
  ->orderBy('yearly_issue', 'desc')
  ->take($perpage)
  ->get();
```

I thought adding the `groupBy('magazine_id')` would help, but it seems as though it only partially helps me. The results is not in the correct order. So, my question then is - is there any easy way around this?

I've been experimenting with various answers to similar questions but I completely fail to implement it.

[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

or

[How to get the latest record in each group using GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by)

More help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
The closest I am currently is this:

```sql
SELECT i1.*, c.name AS image, m.title AS title
FROM issues i1
INNER JOIN covers c ON i1.id = c.issue_id
INNER JOIN magazines m ON i1.magazine_id = m.id
JOIN (SELECT magazine_id, MAX(year) year, MAX(yearly_issue) yearly_issue FROM issues GROUP BY magazine_id) i2
ON i1.magazine_id = i2.magazine_id
AND i1.year = i2.year
-- AND i1.yearly_issue = i2.yearly_issue
WHERE i1.stock ($all ? '>=' : '>') 0
ORDER BY i1.year DESC, i1.yearly_issue DESC
LIMIT $perpage
```

However, it is not giving me the desired result at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add a `MAX` function in the `SELECT` clause for each column to be ordered in `DESC`ending order. The inverse goes for columns ordered in `ASC`ending order, you need to add `MIN` function in the `SELECT` clause.

Your Eloquent query has to include a [raw](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) select:

```php
$issues = DB::table('issues')
    ->select(DB::raw('id, max(year) as year, max(yearly_issue) as yearly_issue, stock, created_at, updated_at, magazine_id'))
    ->groupBy('magazine_id')
    ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('yearly_issue', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

The only **drawback** is that you need to specify each column you want to retrieve. And do not use the `*` selector, it will override the aggregate function in the select clause.

---

**Update**: Seems like adding the `*` selector *before* the aggregate functions in the `SELECT` clause works too. This means that you rewrite the raw select as:

```php
->select(DB::raw('*, max(year) as year, max(yearly_issue) as yearly_issue'))
```

I think putting the `*` selector before makes the aggregate functions overrides their columns.

Comment: Awesome! =) That saved my weekend.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a way to order results before grouping and this answer kept popping up. In my case, it was for a user's message inbox. I needed to display the latest message received by the user in each message thread they were part of. My table looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | sender_id | receiver_id | message | created_at | updated_at |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    |           |             |         |            |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The accepted answer on this question, groups the results and then sorts them. I needed to sort the results by the `created_at` field, descending,  before grouping them so I'd get the latest message from each thread. Anyway, here was my final solution after a lot of digging:

```
$sub = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
return $query->select('*')
             ->from(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
             ->groupBy('sender_id');
```

This constructs the following query:

```
select * from (
    select * from `messages`
    order by `created_at` desc
) as sub
group by `sender_id`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it didn't worked for my specific need, the ->tosql parser isn't parsing the parameters quite well, but running a simple raw sql query solved it for me, added my own solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do something like this:

```
select * 
    from `UserTable` 
where userId=3
    group by `field` desc
    order by `dateActivityComplete` ;
```

In eloquent you would do something like this:
->groupBy('field','desc'), however, ordering the groupBy doesn't seem to be an option in eloquent the same as order by is.

Might be an instance where you have to use a raw query, or possibly the max function.

Wade