# Distinct in Laravel ORM?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following table setup (just to explain my problem here):

```
qid | value | created_at
1      1        2014-01-01 00:10
1      2        2014-01-01 00:12
2      231      2014-01-01 00:10
3      hello    2014-01-01 00:10
```

I would like to get an array with Distinct qids, order by created_at DESC.

So the array should look like (only values for example):

```
 [2, 231, hello]
```

Do i need a "Raw Query, with Distinct on the qid column" - or is there another way with Laravel5 ORM Methods?

Answer (score 4):

You need to order by `created_at` and then group by `qid`.

```
Answer::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('qid')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I use now: $Answers = Answer::where('task_uuid', $taskuuid)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->groupBy('question_uuid')->get(); - but i always gets the first value, not the "newest" - so it looks like that he is ignoring the created_at clause.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could add a groupby on qid to achieve that result.
Include the order by to ensure you get the desired qid.

e.g.

```
->groupBy('qid')
```

Comment: Thanks! I use now: $Answers = Answer::where('task_uuid', $taskuuid)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->groupBy('question_uuid')->get(); - but i always gets the first value, not the "newest" - so it looks like that he is ignoring the created_at clause.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, you may need to try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159465/how-to-order-grouped-results-using-eloquent

Comment: oh thanks, i will try that out! Seems that i need to use the raw query method.