# How to order authors by the latest article

Tags: php, laravel

I am  using Laravel 4 for web development. I defined a Model called Author and Author could post article.
then i need a list of authors, which ordered by the latest article, and the name of authors could not be duplicate.
I using the code like

```
$authors= Author::LeftJoin('articles','author.id','=','articles.author_id')
        ->orderBy('articles.created_at','DESC');
        ->groupBy('author.id')->paginate(16);
```

this note work well. the authors are order by the first article not the last.
could groupBy work on the first row occurred?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order grouped results using Eloquent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159465/how-to-order-grouped-results-using-eloquent)

Comment: You need to run raw DB statements.