# Finding latest message from table, grouped by user in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, message

I have a private messages table on my site and for a while now I have had an inbox and sentbox separate. I want to combine the inbox/sentbox only showing the latest message either to or from a specific user.

TLDR: I want to show the latest message grouped by sent to or from each user.

Example of table

```
|  id | fromuser | fromid | touser | toid | message    |  timestamp            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | user1    |  1     | user2  |  2   | Hello..    |  2015-01-01 00:00:00  |
|  2  | user1    |  1     | user3  |  3   | okay...    |  2015-01-02 00:00:00  |
|  3  | user3    |  3     | user1  |  1   | not....    |  2015-01-03 00:00:00  |
|  4  | user2    |  2     | user3  |  3   | New....    |  2015-01-04 00:00:00  |
|  5  | user2    |  2     | user1  |  1   | With.....  |  2015-01-05 00:00:00  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result i'm looking for when in user 1

```
|  id | fromuser | fromid | touser | toid | message    |  timestamp            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3  | user3    |  3     | user1  |  1   | not....    |  2015-01-03 00:00:00  |
|  5  | user2    |  2     | user1  |  1   | With.....  |  2015-01-05 00:00:00  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the code below I can get it to show one message to or from each user but it shows the oldest message not the newest.

```
mysql_query("SELECT m1.*, users.id AS userid, users.username 
    FROM pm AS m1, pm AS m2, users 
    WHERE ((m1.fromuser='".$_SESSION['userName']."' AND users.id=m1.toid) 
    OR (m1.touser='".$_SESSION['userName']."' AND users.id=m1.fromid)) 
    AND m2.id=m1.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
```

Comment: Why am i not seeing any joins between your tables? how about joining the tables and using limit function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the latest record in each group using GROUP BY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by)

Comment: had a look at that link and that will return all messages, not just messages to or from user logged in.

Comment: then modify that query and add your `...='".$_SESSION['userName']."'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

<s>select * 
      from messages m
      where not exists (
        select 1 
          from messages mm
          where (mm.fromuser = m.fromuser or mm.fromuser = m.touser) AND (mm.touser = m.touser or mm.touser = m.fromuser)
            and mm.timestamp > m.timestamp
        )
        and m.fromuser = 'user1' or m.touser = 'user1';</s>

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f0fb/10).

It would probably be better, going forward, to flag conversations between two users as a particular conversation, then every message belongs to a conversation, and thus it becomes far easier to find conversations the user is involved in, and info about messages related to the conversation. Anyway.

Try this one instead. Ugh.

```
select m.* 
  from messages m 
     left join messages m2 
       on ((m.fromuser = m2.fromuser and m.touser = m2.touser) 
           or (m.fromuser = m2.touser and m.touser = m2.fromuser)) 
         and m.timestamp < m2.timestamp 
  where (m.fromuser = 'user1' or m.touser = 'user1') 
  and m2.id is null;
```

It's likely to be superior to the `not exists` version, even if i do manage to fix that one.

[this fiddle actually works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28eb7/5)

Comment: This seems to be returning more than one row of messages sent to 'user1' from same sender

Comment: correct. which is exactly what the op asked for, as they came from different users

Comment: I replaced 'user1' with '".$_SESSION['userName']."' but it returns more than one message from the same sender

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28eb7/1/0

Comment: I did update the sample data  here a new link sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28eb7/1/0

Comment: yeah sorry. tired. now fiddle is taking ages to respond

Comment: @DavidWright sorry, try now with the replacement query