# Select from all customers the last record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, distinct

I'm trying to get from the statistics table the last record from the last day of each customer.
I want to select the customer with the most sold items from the last day.

The stats are generated every hour so there are multiple statistics from the customer, but I need just the last one.

I tried several commands I just receive errors.

```
 Statistic.where("created_at < ?",1.day.ago).select(:customer_id).distinct.order(created_at: :desc)
```

or

```
Statistic.where("created_at < ?",1.day.ago).select(:customer_id).distinct.last
```

Is the best solution with pluck? Or should I create 2 selects?
I have no idea where I should place 'sold_items'.

this could be also a solution, but I'm not sure.

```
Customer.all.each do |customer|
  stats = customer.statistics.where("created_at < ?",Date.today).last
  count = stats.sold_items if stats.sold_items > count
  best = customer if count = stats.sold_items
end
```

The Models:
customer has_many :statistics - Statistic belongs_to :customer

Comment: could you please add model declarations? 
in order to make your first query to work, you should make a join. so the second.

Comment: do you have a `has_many` `belongs_to` relation between your `Customer` and `Statistic` models ?

Comment: Right. Customer has_many :statistics and Statistic belongs_to :customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Statistic.joins("inner join (select customer_id,max(created_at) as created_at from statistics group by customer_id) as stats2 on statistics.customer_id = stats2.customer_id and statistics.created_at = stats2.created_at").pluck("max(statistics.sold_items)")
```

This will give you the maximum sold items from the customer who sold most items on the last day so far,

Let me walk you through this,

Basically first of all you need the last statistics for each customer. then you need the `maximum` of sold_items from those statistics.

So the nested query `(select customer_id,max(created_at) as created_at from statistics group by customer_id)` is selecting the maximum `created_at` for each customer , then The outer query is joining the actual `statistics` with these results and selecting only those whose fall  under the last date criteria. then at the end `pluck("max(statistics.sold_items)")` select the maximum sold_items from those results.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by) is another link which finds the latest record from each group.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thank you!