# How to fetch last record for each day in a given group of records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
 id | service_name | subscribers_count | date
 1  | service 1    | 1                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:01
 2  | Service 1    | 2                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:02
 3  | Service 1    | 3                 | 2017-07-02 01:01:01
 4  | Service 1    | 2                 | 2017-07-03 01:01:01
 5  | Service 1    | 3                 | 2017-07-04 01:01:01
 6  | Service 2    | 1                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:01
 7  | Service 2    | 2                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:02
 8  | Service 2    | 3                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:03
 9  | Service 2    | 4                 | 2017-07-02 01:01:01
```

It's easy to fetch the last record for each service, but I need more - I need to fetch the last record for each service for each day. This is what I expect to get:

```
2  | Service 1    | 2                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:02
3  | Service 1    | 3                 | 2017-07-02 01:01:01
4  | Service 1    | 2                 | 2017-07-03 01:01:01
5  | Service 1    | 3                 | 2017-07-04 01:01:01
8  | Service 2    | 3                 | 2017-07-01 01:01:03
9  | Service 2    | 4                 | 2017-07-02 01:01:01
```

What's the most effective way to write it?

Comment: Show us the easy part

Comment: @Strawberry here you are
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by

Comment: I can't see how the 'hard' part is any harder than the 'easy' part ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.service_name = t.service_name and
                      date(t2.date) = date(t.date)
               );
```

Comment: (service_name) - although I agree it should be an id

Answer (score 0):

To use your own solution...

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM messages t1
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT from_id
            , SOMETHING HERE
            , MAX(timestamp) timestamp 
         FROM messages 
        GROUP 
           BY from_id
            , SOMETHING HERE
     ) t2
    ON t1.from_id = t2.from_id 
   AND SOMETHING HERE
   AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;
```

This solution is extremely 'effective'. Although you'd only appreciate any difference between this solution and Gordon's on quite a sizeable data set, I suspect that this solution will out-perform that one - although I'd be delighted to be proven wrong.