# Retrieve last record in a group based on string - DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with transactional data in a DB2 database that I want to retrieve the last record, per location and product. The date is unfortunately stored as a YYYYMMDD string. There is not a transaction id or similar field I can key in on. There is no primary key.

| DATE | LOCATION | PRODUCT | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210105 | A | P1 | 4 |
| 20210106 | A | P1 | 3 |
| 20210112 | A | P1 | 7 |
| 20210104 | B | P1 | 3 |
| 20210105 | B | P1 | 1 |
| 20210103 | A | P2 | 6 |
| 20210105 | A | P2 | 5 |

I want to retrieve results showing the last transaction per location, per product, so the results should be:

| DATE | LOCATION | PRODUCT | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210112 | A | P1 | 7 |
| 20210105 | B | P1 | 1 |
| 20210105 | A | P2 | 5 |

I've looked at answers to similar questions but for some reason can't make the jump from an answer that addresses a similar question to code that works in my environment.

Edit: I've tried the code below, taken from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by). It returns multiple rows for a single location/part combination. I've tried the other answers in that question to, but have not had luck getting them to execute.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE DATE > '20210401' AND DATE in (SELECT max(DATE) 
FROM t GROUP BY LOCATION) order by PRODUCT desc
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your attempt at this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example, if your table is called `t` you can do:

```
select * 
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by location, product 
                      order by date desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` to get the last row before a change:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by location, product order by date) as next_lp_date,
             lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_lp_date is null or next_lp_date <> next_date
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just needed to match your keys within the subselect.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t T1
WHERE DATE > '20210401' 
AND DATE in (SELECT max(DATE) FROM t T2 WHERE T2.Location = T1.Location and T2.Product=T1.Product)
```