# Why mysql query is returning wrong Results?

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to find the latest log entries in my MySQL database. I cooked up this query late last night but upon testing today it does not seem to be returning the correct data.

```
SELECT MAX(id), hostName, email, info, time 
FROM log
WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
GROUP BY hostName 
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

The query runs just fine, but none of the other fields seem to match the id column. It grabs the max id number, but the hostName, email, and info do not match the id, and they are not the latest. I've spent a few hours spinning my wheels on this (I'm a MySQL noob and just doing this for fun) so I'm pretty confused now..

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Wow thanks for all the responses! Sorry for the confusion, I should have said "I want the latest log per hostname!" <- That is specifically what I need.

Comment: Why do you need the MAX()? Is ordering by time not enough to get the latest log entries?

Comment: Hmm.. just removed it and I get data that's almost 30 mins old..

Comment: Can you explain the result you want ? "Only the last entry of each host and id" ?

Comment: Edited main post. I want the latest log entry per each hostname

Comment: Something to note about all the index suggestions: while they will help your read performance (i.e. running this query), they will most likely hurt your insert performance. If you're inserting a LOT of rows into this log table, the index maintenance may not be worth saving you the time to run the query.

Comment: Ohhh good to know thank you! Well.. I'm not sure really :/
3 mins to run the query is very bad, I wanted the log to update every few seconds.. but I'm also inserting rows at supposedly up to a few dozen per second..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do the same thing is to `GROUP BY` and then `JOIN` to the log table:

If *"latest"* means the maximum `id`, use a `(hostname, time, id)` index and this:

```
SELECT log.id
FROM 
        log
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id
          FROM log
          WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
          GROUP BY hostName
        ) AS grp
      ON grp.id = log.id ;
```

**UPDATE**: You may alo want to try this one. It just might be more efficient (depending on the hostname distribution) - and would benefit from a index:  `(hostname, id, time)` index:

```
SELECT log.id
FROM 
        log
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id
          FROM log
          GROUP BY hostName
        ) AS grp
      ON grp.id = log.id 
WHERE log.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ;
```

---

If *"latest"* means the maximum `time` (e.g. if `time` is `insertion_time` and is not changed later), use a `(hostname, time)` index and this:

```
SELECT log.*
FROM 
        log
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT hostname, MAX(time) AS max_time
          FROM log
          WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
          GROUP BY hostname
        ) AS grp
      ON  grp.hostname = log.hostname
      AND grp.max_time = log.time ;
```

---

And finally, since everyone forgot to answer the ***"Why mysql query is returning wrong Results?"*** question, here is another question with some useful answers: 
[Why does MySQL add a feature that conflicts with SQL standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards)

Comment: Thank you, I believe I have an index on id as it is the primary key. I'm looking into adding one on hostname now! :)

Comment: Not on `(hostname)` but on `(hostname, id)`

Comment: Hm, I didn't think of the `time` condition. This is not going to be easy.

Comment: I re-read your question. My previous query was wrong. See my edit.

Comment: Does "latest" means the row with the maximum `id` or the one with the maximum `time`?

Comment: Supposedly, the max id and max time will be the same! I would say id would probably be the very latest but I'm not sure. id is autoincremented and time is just the current timestamp at insert.

Comment: If timestamp is updated or changes at updates (like some timestamps are defined), then don't use this. I'll edit again.

Comment: The timestamp per entry will never change once it's made. I simply am inserting new rows with the current time. No updates will ever be made to this table.

Comment: What do you want to happen if a hostname has no recent entry in the log? Not shown at all I guess?

Comment: Correct! That's why I was putting that time limit of an hour. I will have tons of servers come and go as they are virtual machines in the cloud.

Comment: That's done it! .3 seconds and just what I was looking for! Thank you thank you thank you!!! :)

Comment: At the moment only a few dozen

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I am attempting to find the latest log entries in my MySQL database

There is no need to group nor use a subquery. Just try this:

```
SELECT id, hostName, email, info, time FROM log
WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Now you said:

> I want the latest log per hostname!

Then the solution should be this:

```
SELECT l1.id, l1.hostName, l1.email, l1.info, l1.time FROM log l1
LEFT JOIN log l2 on l1.hostName = l2.hostName AND l1.time < l2.time
WHERE l2.time IS NULL
ORDER BY l1.time DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking specifically for one log per hostname!

Comment: I know, I am not good at explaining things I don't know well *embarrased*

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full row that corresponds to the max id for each distinct `hostName`,

```
SELECT id, hostName, email, info, time
FROM log
WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM log WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
     GROUP BY hostName)
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Comment: That query took 177 seconds to run O_O

Comment: Do you have the helpful index on hostName ?

Comment: Negative. I've heard about indexes and really should start researching them.. I'll try and add one..

Answer (score 0):

This is a famous one:

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE log.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM log
    WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
    GROUP BY hostName) T
```