# MySQL count FKs on other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, foreign-keys

Two tables: MEMBER, GROUP.

I want to get name and email from MEMBER table,
and I want get the number of GROUPS a member is registered in.

GROUP has a memberId as FK. So memberId = 1 could have many groupID.

I want a single SQL query to gather info on all the members and how many groups they're in.

Comment: So use a `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the primary key of MEMBER is memberId. Try this

```
SELECT m.name, m.email, count(g.memberId )
FROM `MEMBER` m 
LEFT JOIN `GROUP` g ON g.memberId = m.memberId
GROUP BY m.memberId
```

Comment: I can run it but it gives no results at all.

Comment: is it showing error ? do both tables have data ?

Comment: Ok that was partly the case.. The data I have had no relations. The query must work if the a member isn't registered in any group as well. Now it only displays data if the member is in at least one group.

Comment: @user1121487 updated the answer, try now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, email, count(`GROUP`.id)
FROM `MEMBER` INNER JOIN `GROUP` ON `GROUP`.memberId = MEMBER.memberId
GROUP BY MEMBER.memberId
```

Comment: Have you tested this?  I don't have mysql here, but the `GROUP BY` doesn't look like it will work.

Comment: ~Adam, the edit by ~Buggabill fixes it.  GROUP BY is a reserved word in SQL, but the question used GROUP as a table name.  The backquotes of the table name may fix the SQL.  Better would be to never use an SQL reserve word as a table name (even in an example :) )

Comment: I can run it but it gives no results at all.

Comment: @MarlinPierce My concern is that you have values in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This is not allowed in SQL Server, and I was doubting this was possible with MySql either.

Comment: Same as comment above: It displays data but ONLY if member is registered in at least one group. I must show members with 0 groups as well.

Comment: @AdamWenger: It is allowed in MySQL: [Why does MySQL add a feature that conflicts with SQL standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards)

Comment: ~user1121487 to get members with no groups change INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: ~AdamWenger You are right.  That's the way I learned SQL, after DB2 kept beating me over the head with putting all the non-aggregated fields in the select in the group by.  However, it is predictable what the group by needs to be from the select, so I'm not surprised a later database vendor figures out what to do for me. :)

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for the information and links in your answer.