# Query using count with foreign key involved

Tags: mysql, sql

In the query I am fetching data from three tables : `company`, `classes_by_company`, and `person`. I have a foreign key in all tables with the name `company_id`. I use a left join to mesh the tables with a matching `company_id`. I am trying to find out the amount of classes per company and employees. I am getting values that are not correct for both. Here is a [SQIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803440/1)

```
SELECT a.id, 
a.company_id,
a.status,
COUNT(c.company_id) AS classes_per_company,
COUNT(p.employee_id) AS employees_per_company
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN classes_by_company c
ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN person p
ON a.company_id = p.company_id
GROUP BY a.company_id
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE company
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     company_id int,
     status varchar(20)
    );
CREATE TABLE classes_by_company
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 company_id int,
 class_name varchar(20)
);
CREATE TABLE person
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
employee_id int,
 company_id int,
 person_name varchar(20)
);
```

[image]

Comment: *"classes per company and employees"* .. can you show us your desired result set?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO oh yes! sorry I will add that right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to ask - why does `company` have both `company_id` *and* `id`?  Shouldn't one of them be sufficient?  Regardless of that, your problem is due to the multiplicative nature of joins - that is, if there are 2 employees at a company, and 2 classes, you end up with 4 rows - 1 for each combination (person A + class A, person A + class B, person B + class A, person B + class B).  Due to this, here's the other way the issue is usually solved:

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, a.status,
       c.count AS classes_per_company,
       p.count AS employees_per_company
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM classes_by_company
           GROUP BY company_id) c
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM person
           GROUP BY company_id) p
       ON a.company_id = p.company_id
```

(and the [resulting fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803440/12) - thanks for providing one!)

Note that, while both answers give the correct result, this version is likely to be more performant, as it has a higher chance to be using indices.

Comment: I understand now. Well i was using `id` as just for auto increment and `company_id` as the unique company id but as it being store it doesn't necessarily go in numerical order.

Comment: Ignore "numerical order" out of autogenerated id columns - SQL as a standard essentially states that rows have no inherent order (that's the whole purpose for `ORDER BY`) - things like indices are optimizations.  Doing so probably violates the rule of assigning meaning to surrogate keys.  If you need to know which came first, use a timestamp column (set to UTC).  You should generally only need one internal key per table, either a single column or a composite key (like for cross-reference tables - what happens if a person works for more than one company?).

Comment: Good Point! I am glad I know this now. I will apply it.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to `COUNT(DISTINCT c.company_id)` since your data has entries of the same company_id and class

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.company_id,
       a.status,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS classes_per_company,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.employee_id) AS employees_per_company
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN classes_by_company c ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN person p ON a.company_id = p.company_id
GROUP BY a.id,a.company_id,a.status
```

according to your updated question: you only need `COUNT(DISTINCT p.employee_id)`

also i think you should `COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)` instead of `COUNT(c.company_id)` since you're trying to count classes and not companies.

Comment: An ANSI standard statement would be nice.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO What do you mean by that? I am keen to know.

Comment: Your answer (by MySQL's fault) is not ANSI standard as you're `SELECT`ing columns which are not in your `GROUP BY`. [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) and [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards). If you will ever work on a different SQL platform, you will have bad habits to kick.

Comment: @TinTran but it still shows 1 class for `company_id = 7`. Check the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803440/5)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO that's what you mean, i never select columns that aren't in the group by. I was just in a hurry to post an answer. I'll change my answer to make it proper.

Comment: Yes I skipped over that important line. I will use `COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)` since I am counting by classes.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the other answer is a better anyways :)