# SQL Inner join with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one called games and one called reviews.

I am trying to join these two tables together and have looked through the documentations and also the other questions here on stackoverflow.

```
SELECT games.id, games.title, games.developer, reviews.review, reviews.review_title,
(SELECT review, COUNT(*) 
FROM reviews
GROUP BY review) AS Numberofreviews 
FROM games
INNER JOIN reviews
ON games.ean=reviews.games_ean;
```

The query that i am trying to make is to get a table that shows the list of games and how many reviews each game has recieved.

But when i try implementing the above code i get the error operand should contain one column

Ive looked at other people getting this error but not in the same situation.

Any help would be apprecatied

edit: this is with mySQL

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: what is a DDL? sorry new to databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the subquery into the `from` clause, instead of `reviews` to get the number:

```
SELECT g.id, g.title, g.developer, r.Numberofreviews 
FROM games g inner join
     (SELECT games_ean, COUNT(*) as Numberofreviews
      FROM reviews
      GROUP BY games_ean
     ) r
     on g.ean = r.games_ean;
```

It does not make sense to have a column called `review_title`, because there might be more than one review.

Comment: The review_title column will come into effect later for users to be able to submit a quick summary of their review eg good/bad so that other users can then click it to get a more detailed review. That being said i didnt need to call that column here

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correlated subquery and for the error it clearly says there should be one column from your subquery

```
SELECT 
  g.id,
  g.title,
  g.developer,

  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
  FROM
    reviews 
  WHERE games_ean = g.ean) AS Numberofreviews 
FROM
  games g
  INNER JOIN reviews r 
    ON g.ean = r.games_ean ;
```

Comment: where you have changed reviews to r is that just to shorten it right?

Comment: Not only to shorten it ,also to give an alias to refer it in subquery  like `WHERE games_ean = r.games_ean`

Comment: With this it returns all the reviews which in this case is 5 for every column but im trying to get how many each game has

Comment: @user3187726 see my updated answer there was a mistake in comparsion

Comment: Ah yeh i did the same thing but realised that my WHERE was comparing with itself

Answer (score 1):

You get the error "operand should contain one column" because your subquery returns two columns. Only one is allowed in this situation. However you don't need a subquery at all. Make a [left join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) (in case for no reviews) and [aggregate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) the reviews:

```
SELECT games.*, COUNT(reviews.games_ean)
  FROM games
  LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.games_ean = games.ean
  GROUP BY games.ean;
```

<sub>I assume that `games.*` is functional depended on [`games.ean`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29) (i.e. `games.ean` is unique).</sub>

---

As this statement seems to cause confusion I want to emphasize that a projection on non aggregated attributes in a grouped statement is only defined for attributes which are [functionally depended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) on the the grouped attributes. The statement (given the assumption that `games.ean` is unique) therefore is valid and makes perfect sense!

MySQL allows projections of non aggregated attributes which are not functionally depended! However they are not defined in ANSI-SQL nor are they deterministic as MySQL selects one undefined value for each non aggregated attribute.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of non-ANSI standard `GROUP BY`.

Comment: [Why does MySQL add a feature that conflicts with SQL standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards)

Comment: Sorry, but I think it is compliant. games.ean might not be the primary key but from the context of OP it seems to me that `games.*` is functional dependent on `games.ean`. Otherwise it wouldn't make no sense to use it as a foreign key. Please elaborate more where you see the conflict.

Comment: Nothing more to elaborate. Take an ANSI standard DBMS and try it there. [I did it for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0614f/2)

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I think you understand correctly. If that `games.ean` is a unique key, then the query would not be violating anything. I think you still need to add in the answer why this would be allowed in the case (where `game.ean` is a unique or primary key) and that it is not a good practice to follow in other cases or in general.

Comment: Oh, and you need to correct that `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(reviews.games_ean)` so the count is shown as `0` and not `1` when there is no matching row in the `review` table.

Comment: You can certainly ask that as a new question, and I guarantee it will get closed. [This will probably shed more light on it](http://www.oreillynet.com/databases/blog/2007/05/debunking_group_by_myths.html)

Comment: The *reason* your query violates *ANSI* SQL is because there are columns in your `SELECT` list (`games.*`) which are not aggregated or in the `GROUP BY` clause. The other columns in the `games` table are *not* functionally dependent (`title, developer`).

Comment: If games.ean is unique in games the other columns are [functional depended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) on games.ean. OP's context leads to the conclusion that [games.ean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29) is unique. I stated that assumption a few times. If you think that games.ean is not unique you could have said that. Your assertion that the given query violates ANSI SQL is wrong (and even phrased in your posted references). I'll assume you agree and will remove your downvotes plus your comments.

Answer (score -1):

> The query that i am trying to make is to get a table that shows the list of games and how many reviews each game has recieved.

```
SELECT games.id, games.title, games.developer, COUNT(DISTINCT reviews.*) as reviews_amount
FROM games
LEFT JOIN reviews ON games.ean = reviews.games_ean
GROUP BY games.ean;
```

Comment: Beside that, `GROUP BY reviews.id` doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does the DISTINCT call do

Comment: @user3187726 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of non-ANSI standard `GROUP BY`.