# SQL Group by Subquery ignored

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where a company has an amount of slots, These slots can be filled with persons.. 
I want to do a query where **I can see which companies still have open slots**

This is the query i'm trying but it's giving me the wrong results.

```
select
    name,
    slots,
    (select count(*) from persons) as persons
from companies
where city_id = 3
group by companies.id
```

This should give me a table with the slots, and the amount of personsfilled for that company in the persons table, but it's returning the total amount of persons every time.

This is the result

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You must link persons table with compianies table or another to know if person use a slot. I think you must review your table structure.

Comment: show the table structure of both the tables and your query will return same number since you are counting data from persons table each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JoeTaras said, you need to *join* persons and companies to be able to tell/count which persons belong to which company. If you don't join them somehow, companies and persons will be treated and counted independently which is normally not very useful.

A different sub-query *could* indeed be used, but it's not quite how 'you do it', and will probably be less performant than the straight-forward join.

Example:

```
select
    companies.id
    companies.name,
    companies.slots,
    count(persons.id)
from companies
left outer join persons on companies.id = persons. ...
where companies.city_id = 3
group by companies.id, companies.name, companies.slots
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's also working with only: GROUP BY companies.id.. How come this query is working? i shouldn't of used a subquery then? Thanks!

Comment: MySQL [Extends the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596265/1048425) to allow columns in the select list that are not contained in the group by. If `companies.ID` is the primary key (this seems logical) then only grouping by this is perfectly legitimate since all other fields in `companies` are functionally dependent on this. The problem with this extension arises when you abuse it, for example if you only group by `companies.name`, and select `companies.id` - if you have two companies with the same name and different IDs, then the value returned for `ID` is not deterministic.

Comment: Also +1 for the correct answer, however it would be much better to provide even a brief explanation of what you have done to fix the problem and why. Code only answers have limited use, and don't address the real purpose of Stackoverflow as a question and answer site, not a free code writing service. As the old proverb goes, "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"