# Joining multiple Tables and using Count with MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

So I've got myself in a massive confused mess.

Basically, I have a little social network app and I have 4 different tables I need to combine into one view.

- Table 1 - User posts
- Table 2 - Users
- Table 3 - Likes
- Table 4 - Comments

I then need to return a list of posts, with the user details and then add columns for the number of likes and number of comments for each post respectively.

If a post doesn't have any likes or comments, then ideally we should show a Zero.

The query below joins everything up, but returns multiple rows of everything, as it is returning 1 row for each comment or like as well.

Anyone able to help me combine these together?

```
SELECT *
FROM app_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN app_comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN app_user AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN app_likes AS l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE u.user_banned = 0
AND p.post_public = 1
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Table columns are as follows;

**app_likes**

- like_id
- post_id
- user_id
- liked_date

**app_comments**

- comment_id
- comment_user_id
- post_id
- comment_body
- comment_date

**app_posts**

- post_id
- user_id
- post_content
- post_date
- post_public

**app_user**

- user_id
- user_first
- user_last
- user_avatar
- user_banned

An example of what is returned currently is as follows (chopped down for easiness)

[image]

You'll see the post_id is repeated multiple times.

What I want it to return is the post_id just once, and with the count of 'likes' and 'comments' in new columns (I don't know how to do this).

Simon

Comment: What is your current result and what is your desire result? That will help us to see where is the problem.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I've just edited my question with a snippet of my current output. Basically I need to have 1 instance of each post_id returned and have a count of 'likes' and 'comments' as new columns added automatically.

Comment: @Simon You forgot to use **'GROUP BY p.post_id'**

Comment: @SimonHume The basic should be `GROUP BY` but looks like you have repeated data, duplicated comment and dates so you may want to take a look to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing GROUP BY...

```
SELECT p.*,u.*,count(distinct c.comment_id),count(distinct l.like_id)
FROM app_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN app_comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN app_user AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN app_likes AS l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE u.user_banned = 0
AND p.post_public = 1
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Note that MySQL lets you be sloppy with GROUP BY like this, but a lot of other databases [would require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311034/is-sql-group-by-a-design-flaw#) you to break out the "`p.*`" into explicit `MAX(p.post_id),MAX(p.post_content),` etc.

Comment: Just because MySQL let you be sloopy doesnt mean you should be sloopy  ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.post_id, COUNT(c.post_id) as num_comments, COUNT(l.like_id) as num_likes
FROM app_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN app_comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN app_user AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN app_likes AS l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE u.user_banned = 0
AND p.post_public = 1
GROUP BY  p.post_id
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Group by at the end of your query, like this

```
SELECT *
FROM app_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN app_comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN app_user AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN app_likes AS l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE u.user_banned = 0
AND p.post_public = 1
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` without aggregated function?