# From MySQL To MS SQL, All Columns Invalid?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have the following query that executes perfectly in MySQL, but it is giving me trouble when I execute it on MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT failedlogins.*, siteprofiles.failedLogins AS max,
   COUNT(failedlogins.id) AS total
FROM failedlogins RIGHT JOIN siteprofiles ON failedlogins > 0
WHERE computerName LIKE 'some awesome name' AND timeStamp > 1340752043
GROUP BY computerName
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'failedlogins.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'failedlogins.timeStamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'failedlogins.userName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'siteprofiles.failedLogins' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I think it has something to do with the `RIGHT JOIN`, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Just as side note, if you are not familar with MySQL, I right joined the only row from `siteprofiles` onto the `failedlogins` table. Typically you will see an `=` sign to like two rows togther from multiple tables. In MySQL, if you only select one row to join on a table, and do not use the equals operator to link rows together, it will join the row onto every row that is returned.

Could some one please help me debug the above statement?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the SQL that constructs the `failedlogins` table:

```
CREATE TABLE failedlogins (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "timeStamp" int NOT NULL,
  "computerName" NTEXT NOT NULL,
  "userName" NTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) ;
```

and the `siteprofiles` table:

```
CREATE TABLE siteprofiles (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "siteName" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  "paddingTop" tinyint NOT NULL,
  "paddingLeft" tinyint NOT NULL,
  "paddingRight" tinyint NOT NULL,
  "paddingBottom" tinyint NOT NULL,
  "width" int NOT NULL,
  "height" int NOT NULL,
  "sideBar" text NOT NULL,
  "auto" text NOT NULL,
  "siteFooter" text NOT NULL,
  "author" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  "language" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  "copyright" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  "description" NTEXT NOT NULL,
  "meta" text NOT NULL,
  "timeZone" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  "welcome" text NOT NULL,
  "style" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  "iconType" text NOT NULL,
  "spellCheckerAPI" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "saptcha" text NOT NULL,
  "question" NTEXT NOT NULL,
  "answer" NTEXT NOT NULL,
  "failedLogins" int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("siteName")
);

INSERT INTO siteprofiles (id, siteName, paddingTop, paddingLeft, paddingRight, paddingBottom, width, height, sideBar, auto, siteFooter, author, language, copyright, description, meta, timeZone, welcome, style, iconType, spellCheckerAPI, saptcha, question, answer, failedLogins) VALUES
(1, 'The Bell News Magazine', 0, 0, 0, 0, 260, 180, 'Right', '', '<p>&copy; 2011 The Bell News Magazine</p>', 'The Bell News Magazine', 'en-US', '© 2011 The Bell News Magazine', 'The collaborative, innovative Bell News Magazine', 'The Bell News Magazine, The PAVCS Bell News Magazine, The Pennsylvania Virtual Charter School Bell News Magazine, Pennsylvania Virtual Charter School Bell News Magazine, Bell News Magazine, Bell News, Bell Magazine, The Bell Magazine, The Bell News', 'America/New_York', 'Ads', 'onlineUniversity.css', 'gif', 'jmyppg6c5k5ajtqcra7u4eql4l864mps48auuqliy3cccqrb6b', 'auto', '', '', 5);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `ON failedlogins` - is incomplete condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have edited the question since the first answers were supplied.  The errors to the tune of

> Column 'failedlogins.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

... are due to the fact that although MySQL (in its default configuration) is very lenient about the contents of the `GROUP BY`, other RDBMS are not.  In order to pull in all the other cols from `failedlogins.*`, you need to `JOIN` against a subquery that does the count on its relevant group column only.

```
SELECT
  failedlogins.*, 
  siteprofiles.failedlogins AS max,
  logincount
FROM 
  failedlogins RIGHT JOIN siteprofiles ON failedlogins > 0
  /* Join matches remaining columns to the counts of computerName */
  INNER JOIN (
    /* Subquery gets computerName and count to join against */
    SELECT computerName, COUNT(*) logincount FROM failedlogins GROUP BY computerName
  ) logincounter ON failedlogins.computerName LIKE logincounter.computerName
WHERE failedlogins.computerName LIKE 'some awesome name' AND timeStamp > 1340752043
```

Comment: Hmm... I get this as a result: `Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.`

Comment: @spryno724 Which column is the text or image blob?

Comment: I've updated my question. And for some reason, I can't tag your name anymore in these comments

Comment: @spryno724 Ah, so `failedLogins.computerName` is `ntext` and we're joining on it with `=`.  Try changing the `ON` clause to `ON failedlogins.computerName LIKE logincounter.computerName`.  Is there a reason that column has to be ntext? Is it so long that it cannot be a varchar?  If you can change it, I would recommend making it varchar instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I had tried changing it to `LIKE` with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If `failedlogins` is numeric you need to specify the condition explicitly

```
ON failedlogins > 0
```

Comment: Ah! I have two more questions, if I may. In this case `failedlogins` is numeric, and your suggestion worked. What if it isn't numeric, could I do something like `ON failedlogins != ''`. I'll update my question in a second, with another error that I am receiving.

Comment: amsprich, answered my first question. ;)

Comment: @spryno724: `IS NOT NULL` isn't equal to `!= ''`. So it depends on what you have and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM failedlogins RIGHT JOIN siteprofiles ON failedlogins
```

I believe the ON needs to be a conditional, like:

```
failedlogins is not null
```

Comment: Ok, that was just something that I wasn't used to adding. ;)

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but any idea what might be causing the second issue?

Comment: With GROUP BY you need to specify every column being selected. Alternatively ORDER BY might be more what you're looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777235/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-specify-all-columns-in-a-sql-group-by-clause-why