# Why cant I use GROUP BY in this Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

When i Executed the following query in MS SQL Management Studio it produced an error.

**Query:**

```
select  u.UserName, r.RoleName
from User u
join UserRole ur on ur.UserId = u.UserId
join Role r on r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
group by r.RoleName
```

**Error:**

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'User.UserName' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Its been a while i had used sql and this i supposed was some basic command. But still i cant figure out the reason.

*Note:*

There is no error if I use

> group by r.RoleName, u.UserName

Comment: What are you trying to get as a result? If you `group by RoleName`, you will get one row for each role - and one role can possibly contain many users - so selecting `userName` with it is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This demonstrates the `single-value rule`, which prohibits the undefined results you get when you run a `GROUP BY` query, and you include any columns in the select-list that are neither part of the grouping criteria, nor appear in aggregate functions `(SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.)`. Hope u understand.

**[Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)**

I dont know but may be you want this..

```
select distinct u.UserName, r.RoleName
from User u
join UserRole ur on ur.UserId = u.UserId
join Role r on r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
```

Answer (score 1):

The [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
select  u.UserName, r.RoleName
from User u
join UserRole ur on ur.UserId = u.UserId
join Role r on r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
group by u.UserName,r.RoleName
```

group by is used either with aggregate functions or to filter the duplicates. In sql-server group by needs all columns in select other than aggregate functions.

In the case of mysql, the below query won't throw error. It will pick the first row for each item in group by clause.

```
select  u.UserName, r.RoleName
    from User u
    join UserRole ur on ur.UserId = u.UserId
    join Role r on r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    group by r.RoleName
```

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan I have already provided this in my question. I'm not looking for that solutions. The reason why my first query didn't work is what I need.

Comment: *In sql-server group by needs all columns in select other than aggregate functions.* Can I get some reference on this @PraveenPrasannan?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777235/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-specify-all-columns-in-a-sql-group-by-clause-why

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx