# Why is a group by clause required when rows are limited in where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

fiId is a primary key of Table1. Why does this query return as many rows as there are fiId in table1. The fiId is being limited to 1 row in the where clause. The query performs properly when a group by Table1.fiId is added, surely this should not be needed? Thanks.

```
SELECT                                                                                                           
        Table1.fiId,                                                                       
        SUM(CASE Table2.type IN (4,7)  THEN Table2.valueToSum  ELSE 0 END),
FROM
        Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.fiId = Table3.parentId
               INNER JOIN Table2  ON Table2.leId = Table3.fiId 
WHERE
        Table1.fiId = 76813  AND
        Table2.insId = 431144
```

Comment: You could argue that every non-aggregate expression in the `SELECT` clause *could* be used as an "implicit" `GROUP BY` clause, but unfortunately, that's not how SQL got designed.

Comment: You can omit GROUP BY in your query - just replace "Table1.fiId" in the SELECT with 76813

Comment: Obviously this query will only return rows where FiId  =76813, however it may be that the inner join has more than one record that joins with fiId in the other tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using aggregate functions in your `SELECT` such as `SUM` and `COUNT` when selecting other columns as well, a `GROUP BY` including those additional columns is required. While I don't know the *exact* reason behind this, it definitely helps to put the results in context.

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT Name, Count(Product) as NumOrders
FROM CustomerOrders
GROUP BY Name
```

Here, we *assume* that we will get results like this:

```
Name     NumOrders
------------------
Joe      15
Sally    5
Jim      23
```

Now, if SQL did not require the `GROUP BY`, then what would you expect the output to be? My best guess would be something like this:

```
Name     NumOrders
------------------
Joe      43
Sally    43
Jim      43
```

In that case, while there may in fact be `43` order records in the table, including `Name` doesn't really provide any useful data. Instead, we just have a bunch of names out of context.

For more on this, see a similar question here: [Why do I need to explicitly specify all columns in a SQL "GROUP BY" clause - why not "GROUP BY *"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777235/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-specify-all-columns-in-a-sql-group-by-clause-why)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Assume we add a WHERE name = 'Joe'. I would expect this to be executed first, leaving us with all Joe's products, these are then counted to 15. Clearly this is just not the way it works.

Comment: It should. Remember, though, it's going to count based on the results that come back. In your example with the `INNER JOIN`s, without the `GROUP BY`, then any extra records from the result of that `JOIN` could cause the count to be thrown off. Again, `GROUP BY` is all about putting the result of the aggregates into context