# Select nvarchar values in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has 3 columns, that looks like this:

```
CustomerId, CustomerName, ItemsCount
```

I want to group by `CustomerId`, with the highest `ItemsCount` value, but in the same time selecting the opposite name of the `CustomerId`, knowing that `CustomerId` is not unique and `CustomerName`, I know it's bad design, but is this possible, I'm thinking of using may be`DISTINCT`, or `TOP` if possible.

```
CustomerId   CustomerName   ItemsCount
-------------------------------------------
     1       Iwan               20
     2       Samir              30
     2       Samir              10
```

So I want this result:

```
CustomerId   CustomerName    ItemsCount
--------------------------------------------
     1       Iwan               20
     2       Samir              30
```

I stopped at this:

```
SELECT CustomerId, MAX(ItemsCount) 
FROM Custmers 
GROUP BY ItemsCount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by customer's id and name and find the max of items count.

```
select customerid, customername, max(itemscount) itemscount
from customers
group by customerid, customername
```

Comment: It sound like I left SQL for a long time!. Thanks!

Comment: But is it needed? grouping by either of customerid or customername would suffice I believe.

Comment: It's good practice to have all the non grouped columns be present in the group by clause. Also, [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777235/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-specify-all-columns-in-a-sql-group-by-clause-why). ANSI compliant databases, such as Oracle, won't even allow it

Comment: @GurV: actually the ANSI standard allows to remove columns from the group by that are functional dependent on other grouping columns. If `customerid` is defined as the primary key of the table, then it would be compliant with the SQL standard to leave out the `customername` (but to my knowledge only Postgres implements that correctly)