# GROUP BY clause does not return winner in each group ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return the winner player in each group id, however, the group by function doesnt seem to work. Will appreciate your input on this.

```sql
SELECT
    group_id,
    player_id AS winner_id
FROM players AS p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            sum(first_score) AS total_first,
            first_player
        FROM matches
        GROUP BY first_player
        ) AS a
        ON p.player_id = a.first_player
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            sum(second_score) as total_second,
            second_player
        FROM matches
        GROUP BY second_player
        ) AS b
        ON p.player_id = b.second_player
    GROUP BY p.group_id
    ORDER BY
        coalesce(total_first, 0) + coalesce(total_second, 0) DESC,
        player_id ASC
```

Comment: U need to group both group_id and player_id for group by. For Group By all selected Item must be use without any aggregation function.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? Please be more specific. That problem description indicates you haven't analysed your problem yet

Answer (score 0):

in your query no aggregate function so no need group  by just use distinct

```
select distinct group_id, player_id as winner_id
from players as p
left join 
(SELECT sum(first_score) as total_first, first_player
from matches
group by first_player) as a
on p.player_id = a.first_player
left join 
(SELECT sum(second_score) as total_second, second_player
from matches
group by second_player) as b
on p.player_id = b.second_player    
order by coalesce(total_first,0)+coalesce(total_second,0) desc, player_id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to have each field in levels of grouping, this may be a solution:

```sql
SELECT
    group_id,
    player_id AS winner_id
FROM players AS p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            sum(first_score) AS total_first,
            first_player
        FROM matches
        GROUP BY first_player
        ) AS a
        ON p.player_id = a.first_player
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            sum(second_score) as total_second,
            second_player
        FROM matches
        GROUP BY second_player
        ) AS b
        ON p.player_id = b.second_player
    GROUP BY
        p.group_id,
        p.player_id
    ORDER BY
        coalesce(total_first, 0) + coalesce(total_second, 0) DESC,
        player_id ASC
```

When using GROUP BY you [must specify sequence of all fields in grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777265/70157), so the statement is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sum the first and second score for each player, and then choose the one that has the highest value for the group.

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.group_id) p.group_id, v.player, SUM(score)
FROM matches m CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (first_player, first_score),
             (second_player, second_score)
    ) v(player, score) JOIN
    players p
    ON p.player_id = v.player
GROUP BY p.group_id, v.player
ORDER BY p.group_id, SUM(score) DESC;
```

Note that your `LEFT JOIN` approach is dangerous, because there might be some player, some time, some where, who is never first but always second.