# Laravel eloquent GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, group-by, eloquent

I have four tables: **`supplies`**, **`stocks`**, **`stock_ins`**, and **`stock_outs`**. In the **`Stock`** controller, I want to sum the total **`stock_out`** for each supply .

For this, I have used the following query:

```
 $supplies = Stock::select(
            'supplies.name', 
            'stocks.supply_id',
            'stocks.id',
            'stocks.stock',
            'stock_ins.quantity as stock_in_quantity',
            DB::raw('SUM(stock_outs.quantity) as stock_out_quantity')
        )
        ->join('supplies', 'stocks.supply_id', '=', 'supplies.id')
        ->leftJoin('stock_ins', 'stocks.supply_id', '=', 'stock_ins.supply_id')
        ->leftJoin('stock_outs', 'stocks.id', '=', 'stock_outs.stock_id')
        ->groupBy('stocks.supply_id', 'supplies.name' , 'stocks.stock','stock_ins.quantity','stocks.id') 
        ->get();
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'galaxy.supplies.name' isn't in GROUP BY
```

I've also tried to run the raw query in MySQL, which is showing the desired result:

```
SELECT
  supplies.name,
  stocks.supply_id,
  stocks.id,
  stocks.stock,
  stock_ins.quantity AS stock_in_quantity,
  SUM(stock_outs.quantity) AS stock_out_quantity
FROM
  stocks
  INNER JOIN supplies ON stocks.supply_id = supplies.id
  LEFT JOIN stock_ins ON stocks.supply_id = stock_ins.supply_id
  LEFT JOIN stock_outs ON stocks.id = stock_outs.stock_id
GROUP BY
  stocks.id
```

Comment: Maybe you need to include all non-aggregated columns from the SELECT list in the GROUP BY clause. Something like this: `->groupBy('stocks.id', 'stocks.supply_id', 'supplies.name', 'stocks.stock', 'stock_ins.quantity')`

Comment: yeah also tried this, but got 2 rows in result, don't know why.

Comment: Maybe because there are multiple rows in either the `stock_ins` or `stock_outs` tables for a single combination of `stocks.supply_id` and `stocks.id`

Comment: yes , there are multiple stock ids in stock outs which could lead to this result . however the question remains: why do i have to provide all columns in groupBY clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777235/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-specify-all-columns-in-a-sql-group-by-clause-why

Comment: not entirely but was helpful.  and btw thanks for pointing out my mistake , in  "why multiple rows were coming "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the raw query in MySQL is running and shows you the desired result, you can replicate this behavior in your Laravel application by turning off strict mode.
in config\database.php
add `strict=>false`.

```
     'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false, // this line
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

then update your group by stocks.id as in your raw sql query

```
        ->groupBy('stocks.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can change this strict mode in run time as below.

```
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
\DB::reconnect();
```

> Your query...

```
    config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);
\DB::reconnect();
```